# Accessing microphone from firefox add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am exploring [wit.ai](http://wit.ai) and want to try it out in firefox add-on. I followed this web quick start [guide](https://wit.ai/docs/web/0.7.0/quickstart) which explain how to implement in a webpage.

If I run it as a webpage, firefox pop-up for microphone permission but when I implement the same as an add-on, firefox doesn't pop-up for permission and log from javascript says, Microphone is connecting implying that it still doesn't have the permission.

How do I get permission for accessing microphone from firefox add-on?

Answer (score 1):

I am actually working the same thing.

This is how to do it - https://github.com/Noitidart/FoxSpeak/issues/4

We see here - https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/modules/webrtcUI.jsm#170

```
  receiveMessage: function(aMessage) {
    switch (aMessage.name) {

      // Add-ons can override stock permission behavior by doing:
      //
      //   var stockReceiveMessage = webrtcUI.receiveMessage;
      //
      //   webrtcUI.receiveMessage = function(aMessage) {
      //     switch (aMessage.name) {
      //      case "rtcpeer:Request": {
      //        // new code.
      //        break;
      //      ...
      //      default:
      //        return stockReceiveMessage.call(this, aMessage);
      //
      // Intercepting gUM and peerConnection requests should let an add-on
      // limit PeerConnection activity with automatic rules and/or prompts
      // in a sensible manner that avoids double-prompting in typical
      // gUM+PeerConnection scenarios. For example:
```

That they allow addons to inject into here. I haven't had time to finish this, but if you do finish before me please do share. :)